# GeoSever Helm Chart (Kubernetes)

Tags: geoserver

Anyone know if Extensions or Plugins can be allowed inside GeoServer Helm Chart version that's here.

https://github.com/camptocamp/helm-geoserver-cloud

may be few arguments similar to below,

`helm install geoserver . --set geoserver.ARG=DOWNLOAD_ALL_COMMUNITY_EXTENSIONS:1" --set geoserver.ARG=DOWNLOAD_ALL_STABLE_EXTENSIONS:1`

Docker does allow you to add extensions like below,

`docker run -d -p 8600:8080 --name geoserver -e STABLE_EXTENSIONS=charts-plugin,db2-plugin kartoza/geoserver:${VERSION}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care, you are mixing two things:

- https://github.com/camptocamp/helm-geoserver-cloud is a HELM chart to deploy the Cloud Nativer version of GeoServer, which is different from the normal version.
- The kartoza Docker uses the normal version of GeoServer.

Hence you cannot use the options of the Kartoza docker with the CampToCamp HELM Chart.

You should use instead https://github.com/kartoza/charts/tree/develop/charts/geoserver.